# How to downgrade to a previous game's version?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Is it possible to downgrade to a previous version of Europa Universalis 4?

**If so, how?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**

Right-Click EU4 in your Steam Library. Select Properties, select the Betas tab.

Click on the drop down menu at the top, which should say "NONE - Opt out of all beta programs".
Here you can select all the old versions to play, all the way down to 1.4.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is no longer correct as of 1. october 2018.

To change version you now have to do the following steps:

First, get the code to access beta-versions in Steam

> 1. Go to https://accounts.paradoxplaza.com/games and log in (or create) your Paradox Account.
> 2. Scroll Down
> 3. Find "Access Earlier Versions"
> 4. Click "Show"
> 5. Copy the code

Then revert to older versions in Steam.

> 1. Go to your Steam Library and select Europa Universalis
> 2. Right-click and select Properties.
> 3. Under the “BETAS” tab.
> 4. Enter the relevant code retrieved from Paradox Plaza and click “CHECK CODE”.
> 5. Select the version you wish to play and wait for Steam launcher to finalize the switch.
>
> If the previous step fails, exit the game, right click properties, local files, Verify integrity of game files and wait for all files to be verified.

[More info on Paradox' forum](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/changes-to-playing-previous-versions-of-pds-titles.1120883/&utm_source=launch-steam&utm_medium=launcher&utm_content=post&utm_campaign=eu_eu_20180924_pla_dd)