# Can I roll a Steam game back to a previous version?

Tags: steam, no-mans-sky

The new No Man's Sky update (PC) has rendered my game practically unplayable with how often it crashes. Is there a way to roll it back to the previous version on Steam, at least until they fix the bugs?

(The question "[How to downgrade to a previous game's version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261868/how-to-downgrade-to-a-previous-games-version)" seems to be specific to a particular game from one particular developer, in beta, and the solutions do not appear to apply.)

Comment: In the case of no mans sky you can change to the experimental branch which already has some fixes for the new version. To change to the experimental branch you right click the game go to properties then the beta tab. On this tab change the drop down box to the experimental branch. You can also turn off multiplayer in game which will also fix some of the current crashes related to the hub.

Comment: Can you rather take a break from this game? If launch fail, give it some time. You are basically a beta-tester now (a role what I never understand, talking about those pre-purchases with beta pass). I recall Diablo 3 launch days, was so many complains and people were complaining, trying again and complaining. It was totally fine after 2 weeks, the hardest part is not to play the game you want to play ;)